# change on WPF's designer view doesn't work

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, c#

I'm working on a wpf project , it was working and I didn't have any problems with it but now I don't know why it doesn't take the changes I do in properties window . I change width and heights and things like WindowState and none of them works when I press f5 and debug the project . 
I'll be appreciated if someone can help me with this
thanks

Comment: Does the XAML editor report any errors?

Comment: On a side-note. I did have issues with something similar back in the days of VS2008 where *sometimes* changes to my XAML would not be reflected when running my code by hitting F5 in the designer. The solution to this was almost always to do a full rebuild.

Comment: I suspect that I comment out some of my xaml tags and it reported some errors and the I did undo my changes . but that shouldn't really have this effect .

Comment: I used the debug>build solution(f6) and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

the designer in vs2k10 is not the best.  it is WAY better then the one in vs2k8.  that said...if you are not seeing your changes when you run the app, it is likely your code.

Comment: +1 for truth.  Even though the designer is improved, you'll still be better off if you write the xaml out by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a manual rebuild does it work?

In that case you probably don't have you project being built. Go to menu 'Build' -> 'Configuration Management' and make sure every checkbox is checked for the current(active) configuration.